# using sed and looping through input strings

Tags: bash, sed

I am having problem looping over a sed command. I have multiple inputs defined in files.txt and those are used in the input and should be in the output filename as defines in $FILE

```
mapfile -s 1 -t files < files.txt
echo "${files[@]}"

for FILE in ${files[@]}; do

sed -n '/^>Gene-$FILE/{p;n;p}' mature.dna.fa > mature.dna.$FILE.fa;
done
```

files.txt

```
abu
gno
```

Comment: Use double quotes, not single quotes, so the variable will be expanded.

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but you're missing a `done` to terminate the loop.

Comment: barmar solved it.